# How can I create a delegate within an F# type equivalent to a delegate in a C# class?

Tags: f#, delegates, signals, observer-pattern, godot

I am writing code for a game in Godot and I'm using F# as my programming language. I'm kind of pushing the boundary a bit since they are still in late alpha support for C#. It isn't always easy to find solutions to problems from converting patterns from C# to F#. I'm running into an issue declaring my delegates in a way that the Godot Editor will recognize my delegate `Signal`s. In my eyes, this borders on the x-y problem but I'm working in the constraints of the Godot system.

I'm looking to be able to declare the F# equivalent of this class. The key here is that the `[Signal]` function annotation is what tells the editor that this delegate can be used as a signal in their observer pattern. Having the delegate declared within the class also locks the scope of that delegate to that class. Only that class will raise that signal.

```cs
using Godot;

public class GodotNode : Node
{
    [Signal]
    public delegate void MyDelegate();

    public void SendSignal
    {
        EmitSignal(nameof(MyDelegate));
    }
}
```

I have done by best to try to recreate this within F# but I'm really falling short on how to nest the delegate within another type. From everything I have seen this isn't exactly possible but I was wondering if there was something else I can do.

```ml
open Godot

(* This is the closest I have been able to get to. *)
[<Signal>]
type MyDelegateSignal = delegate of Unit -> Unit

type GodotNodeFs()
   inherit Node

    (* But I need the equivalent of this
    [<Signal>]
    type MyDelegateSignal = delegate of Unit -> Unit    *)

    member this.SendSignal =
        this.EmitSignal(nameof MyDelegate)
```

Worst case scenario, I know I can at least get this working by pushing this back down to the C# code. At the moment in Godot, every class needs to be in C#. So all F# classes are inherited by a C# wrapper class.

```cs
public class GodotNode : GodotNodeFs
{  // ... put signals and emitters in base class
}
```

Comment: F# does not support nested type definitions, so I don't think you'll be able to do this, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm afraid this is impossible at the moment, but probably will be in the next release. Here's an issue: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/277, it appears to have Don Syme's blessing.

Comment: That seems like a promising step for this issue in the future. Another important thing to note is that the target framework is locked to 4.7.2 as per godot as well

Comment: Godot C# support is stable, against .NET 4.7.2. However, you are not really locked. You can edit the project file and set something else. With the caveat that some things may break if you do that. I'm unaware of problems with .NET 4.8. However .NET 5 has some known issues. I believe the intention is to make .NET 6 the next stable.

Comment: That is great to know. Thank you for pointing this out

Comment: After looking at open issues and talking to a couple people about C# support in Godot... First, there is no support for UWP. Second, news: Godot 3.3 brings official support for .NET 5, if you find issues with it please report them. Third, I have a few recommendations for using it: 1. Use Visual Studio Code, the Godot editor still lacks auto-complete et.al. 2. Don't export collections from C# scripts (Issue 41309). 3. If you set signals from the Godot editor to C# scripts, the editor does the wrong thing (it creates a method out of the class, and you have to move it. It is an annoyance).